# Firebase functions + Firestore: ignoreUndefinedProperties not working inside transactions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase-functions with Firestore and I want to able to save objects with nullable fields.

I updated the `ignoreUndefinedProperties` option to `true` but it's not working inside transactions (as it worked outside firebase-functions).

this is my code:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });

admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
    const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`${path}/${id}`);
    ...
    transaction.update(docRef, data);
});
```

and when I save objects with nullable fields I always got:

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. "undefined" values are only ignored in object properties. undefined undefined
```

when I remove the nulls, the updating succeed

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Is this the code of your `index.js` file? If yes, this is not the code of a Cloud Function. Can you also show the value of `data`?

Comment: In addition `const docRef = firestore().doc(...);` doesn't seem to be correct. You should do `const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(...);`

Comment: I just wrote the relevant code. there are several typos but this is not the issue.. when the updating code run without transaction, everything works fine.

Comment: If you don’t share more code, in particular the value of `data` I have doubts someone will be able to help you

Comment: Can you share the Firestore database screenshot and also what is there in `data`?

Comment: It's a bug in firebase. you can check yourself similar scenario (updating of data with nullable fields inside a transaction)

Comment: Before stating it as a bug it will be really beneficial if you can share the function code, Firestore Database screenshot and what is there inside `data`. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue and was able to isolate that it's due to an `undefined` variable inside a map. It only happens when using transactions inside the cloud function and when directly using the document reference from the CF.

The fix is to instantiate a new document reference that uses your Firestore instance that has `ingoreUndefinedProperties` set to `true`:

```
export default region('europe-west1')
  .firestore.document('collection/{docID}')
  .onCreate((snap) => {
    const db = getFirestore();
    const changes= {} // changes to the

    return db
      .runTransaction((t) => {
        const ref = db.doc(snap.ref.path); // <--- This is the important piece: 
                                          // we create a ref with our firestore instance 
                                          // based on the path of the FCF ref
        t.update(ref, changes);
        return Promise.resolve();
      })
  });

)
```